# Object reference error in a if condition

Tags: c#

```
if (pulList.Where(p => p.user.UserId == EndUserInfo.UserId && p.Writable == true).Count() == 0)
```

I m using the same code in 2 places. At the 1st method it is working fine but at the second method it is throwing object reference error. can any one help on this?

Comment: What's the *exact* error message?

Comment: Put both method codes

Comment: In the 1st method 
if (pulList.Where(p => p.user.UserId == EndUserInfo.UserId && p.Writable == true).Count() == 0)
                KnownErrorException.Throw("eFILEWRITAC01");

In the second method:
if (pulList.Where(p => p.user.UserId == EndUserInfo.UserId && p.Writable == true).Count() == 0)
                Iswritable = false;

Comment: In the failing method `p.user == null`, probably.

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
this is the error

Comment: Yeah. `p` itself could be `null`, too.

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
if (pulList.Where(p => p.user.UserId == EndUserInfo.UserId && p.Writable == true).Count() == 0)
```

to:

```
if(pulList!=null)
    if (!pulList.Any(p => p.user.UserId == EndUserInfo.UserId && p.Writable == true))
        /// empty result
```